# How to select only one child in a list of classes

Tags: css

I am using a series of submit buttons for a navigation menu (the submit value will be the navigation method throughout the site).  I have created a dropdown menu with a flyout from the dropdowns.  However, I cannot figure out how to isolate only the hovered element in the dropdown to show it's flyout.  All dropdown items either show all submenus or none.  I have tried using the > and + child selectors in different areas.  Can anyone please help?

My CSS:

```
/* Dropdown Button */
.ddb-container {
width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #faebca;
    font-family: Arial;
    margin-top: 75px;
    padding-left: 150px;
    z-index: 1;
    border-top: 3px black solid;
    border-bottom: 3px black solid;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}

.ddb-container button {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: none;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.ddb-container button:hover {
    background-color: #dbcfa4;
}

.ddb-dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 14px;    
    font-weight: bold;
}

.ddb-dropdown .dropbtn {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.ddb-dropdown .dropbtn:hover {
    background-color: #dbcfa4;
}

.ddb-dropdown .dropdown-level1 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #faebca;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 12px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.ddb-dropdown:hover .dropdown-level1 {
    display: block;
}

.ddb-dropdown .dropdown-level1 .dropdown-level2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #faebca;
    min-width: 160px;
    margin-left: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 12px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 2;
}

.ddb-dropdown  .dropdown-level1:hover  .dropdown-level2 {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='ddb-container'>
<button type='submit' name='submit' value='0'>Home</button>
<div class='ddb-dropdown'>
    <div class='dropbtn'>Sales</div>
        <div class='dropdown-level1'><button type='submit' name='submit' value='#1'>Link 1</button><br /><br />
        <button type='button'>Link 2 ></button><br />
            <div class='dropdown-level2'>
            <button type='submit' name='submit' value='#1'>Sublink 1</button><br />
            <button type='submit' name='submit' value='#2'>Sublink 2</button><br />
            <button type='submit' name='submit' value='#3'>Sublink 3</button><br /><br />
            </div><br />
        <button type='submit' name='submit' value='#3'>Link 3</button><br /><br />
        <button type='submit' name='submit' value='#4'>Link 4</button><br /><br />
        <button type='button'>Link 5 ></button><br />
            <div class='dropdown-level2'>
            <button type='submit' name='submit' value='#1'>Sublink 1</button><br />
            <button type='submit' name='submit' value='#2'>Sublink 2</button><br />
            <button type='submit' name='submit' value='#3'>Sublink 3</button><br /><br />
            </div><br /><button type='submit' name='submit' value='#6'>Link 6</button><br /><br />
        </div>
</div>

<div class='ddb-dropdown'>
    <div class='dropbtn'>Purchasing</div>
</div>
<div class='ddb-dropdown'>
    <div class='dropbtn'>Inventory</div>
</div>
<div class='ddb-dropdown'>
    <div class='dropbtn'>Accounting</div>
</div>
<div class='ddb-dropdown'>
    <div class='dropbtn'>Documents</div>
</div>
<div class='ddb-dropdown'>
    <div class='dropbtn'>Tools</div>
        <div class='dropdown-level1'>
            <button type='submit' name='submit' value='#1'>Tools Link 1</button><br /><br />
            <button type='submit' name='submit' value='#2'>Tools Link 2</button><br /><br />
            <button type='submit' name='submit' value='#3'>Tools Link 3</button><br /><br />
            <button type='button'>Tools Link 4 ></button><br />
                <div class='dropdown-level2'>
                    <button type='submit' name='submit' value='#1'>Sublink 1</button><br />
                    <button type='submit' name='submit' value='#2'>Sublink 2</button><br />
                    <button type='submit' name='submit' value='#3'>Sublink 3</button><br /><br />
                </div><br />
            <button type='submit' name='submit' value='#5'>Tools Link 5</button><br /><br />
            <button type='submit' name='submit' value='#6'>Tools Link 6</button><br /><br />
        </div>
    </div>
<div class='ddb-dropdown'>
    <div class='dropbtn'>Employees</div>
</div>
<div class='ddb-dropdown'>
    <div class='dropbtn'>Administration</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would be better to show the HTML that is rendered to the browser, so we don't need to recreate it from your PHP

Comment: Thank you, Jon.  I edited it to show HTML

Comment: Not that this will fix your problem, but why use `button` instead of `a` for links? `a` was designed to be used for links. Also using `br` for spacing is a bad practice, use `margin` in CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

With the HTML you currently have you can't get what you want with pure CSS. You would need javascript. Refactoring your HTML we can do this with CSS.

While it is not necessary to replace your `buttons` with `a`, it makes more sense to use links for navigation, make sure to use the correct url in the `href` attributes.

We could have achieved the hover effect by removing the `br` tags and using the adjacent sibling selector (`+`) but when hovering over the sub-menus the previous sibling would lose the hover and the sub-menu would disappear.

By creating a hierarchy we can keep the sub-menus active as while they are receiving a hover, so is their parent. Nested lists are a common way of marking up this hierarchy.

The following is a truncated version to get you on your way.

```css
/*Basic List  Reset*/

ul.ddb-container,
ul.ddb-container ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}


/*Basic Link Reset*/

ul.ddb-container a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.ddb-container a:link,
ul.ddb-container a:visited {
  color: #000;
}


/*Dropdown Magic*/

.ddb-container  ul {
  display: none;
}

.ddb-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: #faebca;
  font-family: Arial;
  margin-top: 75px;
  padding-left: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-top: 3px black solid;
  border-bottom: 3px black solid;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.ddb-container > li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: transparent;
  position:relative;
  overflow:visible;
}

.ddb-container li:hover {
  background-color: #dbcfa4;
}

.ddb-dropdown .dropdown-level1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #faebca;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 12px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  text-align:left;
  top:26px;
  left: 0;
}

.ddb-dropdown .dropdown-level1 .dropdown-level2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #faebca;
  min-width: 160px;
  margin-left: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 12px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 2;
}

.ddb-dropdown ul > li {
padding: 1em 0;
}

.ddb-container  li:hover > ul {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul class='ddb-container'>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class='ddb-dropdown'>
    <a href="#">Sales</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-level1">
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2 ></a>
        <ul class='dropdown-level2'>
          <li><a href="#">Link2 Sublink 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link2 Sublink 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link2 Sublink 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 5 ></a>
        <ul class='dropdown-level2'>
          <li><a href="#">Link5 Sublink 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link5 Sublink 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link5 Sublink 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Purchasing</a></li>
</ul>
```